# Calculating Rainfall for four quarters in a user-defined number of years

Tags: java

I'm new to Java, and am attempting to do an assignment...but am feeling lost right about now. We haven't been introduced to arrays yet, so our vocabulary is a bit limited.

1.) Modify your current code so that it will handle multiple years of rainfall data. Give the option to the user to supply the actual number of years they want to enter in the program for evaluation. This program must output the year (i.e. Year 1, Year 2, etc.) for most rainfall and the year with the least amount of total rainfall.

Below is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test2OF
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   { 
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
      double[] rainfall = new double[4]; 
      double totalRainfall = 0.0; 
      double max = 0, min  = 0;
      int year = scan.nextInt();
      int maxQuarter = 1;
      int minQuarter = 1;

      // Prompt user for the number of years
      System.out.println("Enter the number of years: ");
      year = scan.nextInt();

      for (int i=0; i < year*4; i++) 
      { 
         System.out.print("Enter rainfall for quarter " + (i+1) + ": "); 
         rainfall[i] = scan.nextDouble(); 
         totalRainfall += rainfall[i]; 
         if (i == 0)
         {
            max = min = rainfall[i];
         }

         {
            if (rainfall[i] > max) {
               max = rainfall[i];
               maxQuarter = i + 1;
            }
            if (rainfall[i] < min) {
               min = rainfall[i];
               minQuarter = i + 1;
            }
         }
     }

   System.out.println("Total rainfall = "+totalRainfall); 
   System.out.println("Average rainfall = "+(totalRainfall / 4.0)); 
   System.out.println("Max quarter rainfall = "+ max);
   System.out.println("Min quarter rainfall = " + min);
   System.out.println("Max quarter rainfall = "+ maxQuarter);
   System.out.println("Min quarter rainfall = " + minQuarter);

   }//end main 
}//end class
```

Upon compiling, I get this exception when I try to put data in for quarter 5.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
    at Test2OF.main(Test2OF.java:22)
```

I'm also pretty clueless as to how I can specify what year had the most/least amount of rainfall at the end.

Your help is appreciated!  Thank you very much.

Comment: You don't have enough elements in rainfall. You need year * 4 elements. Don't size it until you know the number of years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**problem:**

```
year*4
```

Your `rainfall` is only of a size 4 which means it is only good for 1 year which has 4 quarter.

**solution:**

You need to calculate the number of quarter of the specified number of years and then resize your array by using `year*4`

**sample:**

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
  double[] rainfall; 
  double totalRainfall = 0.0; 
  double max = 0, min  = 0;
  int year = 0;
  int maxQuarter = 1;
  int minQuarter = 1;

  System.out.println("Enter the number of years: ");
  year = scan.nextInt();
  rainfall = new double[year*4]
```

**EDIT:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
   double[] rainfall; 
   int curyear = 0;
   double totalRainfall = 0.0; 
   double max = 0, min  = 0;
   int year = 0;
   int maxQuarter = 1;
   int minQuarter = 1;

   // Prompt user for the number of years
   System.out.println("Enter the number of years: ");
   year = scan.nextInt();
   rainfall = new double[year*4];
   for (int i=0; i < year*4 + 1; i++) 
   { 
       if((i % 4) == 0 && i != 0)
       {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("YEAR: " + ++curyear );
            System.out.println("Total rainfall = "+totalRainfall); 
            System.out.println("Average rainfall = "+(totalRainfall / 4.0)); 
            System.out.println("Max quarter rainfall = "+ max);
            System.out.println("Min quarter rainfall = " + min);
            System.out.println("Max quarter rainfall = "+ maxQuarter);
            System.out.println("Min quarter rainfall = " + minQuarter);
            System.out.println();
            if(i == (year*4))
                break;
       }

      System.out.print("Enter rainfall for quarter " + (i+1) + ": "); 
      rainfall[i] = scan.nextDouble(); 
      totalRainfall += rainfall[i]; 
      if (i == 0)
      {
         max = min = rainfall[i];
      }

      {
         if (rainfall[i] > max) {
            max = rainfall[i];
            maxQuarter = i + 1;
         }
         if (rainfall[i] < min) {
            min = rainfall[i];
            minQuarter = i + 1;
         }
      }


  }



}//end main
```

Comment: Hey Thanks!  I made the adjustments to my code and I can gather the right amount of data (i.e. 2 years = 8 quarters).  Do you know how I could assign "Year 1" for quarters 1-4 and then "Year 2" for quarters 5-8 (etc. etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

```
new double[4];  this is wrong.
```

if you get size from user then why you initialized?

give size after user provide size like `new double[year];`

Answer (score 0):

First thing I notice right off of the bat is

```
Int year = Scanner.nextInt();
Blahblahblah
year = Scanner.nextInt();
```

Don't give year a value yet.

```
Int year;
Year = scanner.nextInt();
```

As for the rest I don't know if I want to help you on this. It is unethical to assist you because the point of this is to learn. Note that it is perfectly fine to tell you professor that you were unable to complete the assignment and that he would be of better assistance than the internet.

Sent from iPad so please excuse spelling and capitalization mistakes